# How to let a div inside my list-item make the list-item grow

Tags: css

Hard to explain this one, but here it goes:

I'm using jQuery to add a `div` to the content of a `list-item`.

What I would like to achieve is that the `list-item` grows to the height of the `div` which was just added.

Please check out the following website: http://pieterhordijk.com

When you hover over to top menu the `div` is added to the menu-item.

Requirements:

Only the CSS of the added div  may be changed.

No JavaScript solutions.

[EDIT] The div has to keep `position: relative;`

Is this possible?

Thanks for all your help in advance!

Comment: If you want *only CSS* solutions, you might consider removing the jquery tag, just to remove the incentive to provide jQuery solutions.

Comment: @David: done. just added it to show the div was added with jQuery. But I think you might be right.

Comment: What is the point of adding the div to the li? Maybe if you tell us what you're trying to accomplish in the end there may be a better solution.

Comment: @wdm too long story to explain ;) But trust me I have tried many other solutions for the problem, and I don't think there is a better solution than adding the div. Thanks anyway though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are floating the LI and giving it a fixed height, so, no...you can't do this unless you're willing to touch the CSS of the LI.

Comment: arrrggh you're right. Looks like I have to resort to a JavaScript solution after all :( Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `height:auto;` in the css of your `<li>` elements, then play with `z-index` to make it appear on top of other elements. You can also set `min-height:22px;` if you want to keep the minimum height, or just put an element inside with the proper size to force it.